# Use Firebase SSL Hosting for two different web applications

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

It appears that I can only have one Top Level Domain (TLD) associated with one firebaseapp SSL hosting.  Is that true?

For example, I'd like https://x.example.com to go to my https://x.firebaseapp.com and https://y.example.com to go to my https://y.firebaseapp.com

When I try I see: (see image below) (I'm using https://city.tidalforce.org/ for a different firebase app at https://cityregister.firebaseapp.com/ but I'd like to use the same domain for another app with another full name such as https://y.tidalforce.org

Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short no, although you may be able to host different apps in different subfolders like https://example.com/x, https://example.com/y and if they have javascript router for example, if you are using Angular for front-end and using Angular-router or something you will nee to provide appropriate rewrite rules like:

```
"rewrites": [ {
  "source" : "/x/**",
  "destination" : "/x/index.html"
},
{
  "source" : "/grid/**",
  "destination" : "/grid/index.html"
} ]
```

to rewrite url requests from that folder to route correctly.

Hope it helps :)